# Putting my GitHub pull request ahead of someone else's

Tags: git, github

It's not just an ego thing.  We keep a series of foreign language translation files on GitHub and use a service to provide translation services.  The workflow involves going to their website and downloading the translated files, doing a quick file formatting massage, then uploading to GitHub for others to use.

Unfortunately someone forgot to update the translations from the service, someone who's out of the office for a couple of days, and they left a pull request on GitHub with the same files I'm going to be updating (with correct translations.)

There's not a 100% overlap between their PR and mine, so I don't really want to close theirs (but will if that's the best way) but I'd like to put mine in front of the line so to speak, and let them worry about merging any changes into their PR.  I'm open to suggestions about how to do this as painlessly as possible.

Comment: This seems more like communication issue than a technical one. It might be better suited for [programmers.se], but even there this seems borderline off-topic...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a note that your PR should be merged before theirs.

Comment: I thought that might be all I needed to do here, but wanted to confirm (especially given the massive overlap .) thank you.